# Dealing with Oracle ARCHIVELOG during huge updates

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, update, archive-log

It's required to update columns with metadata globally in all rows of all tables in DB. Let's say every table has a column `MY_META` and the aim is roughly

```
update ANOTHER_TABLE set MY_META = 'HELLO'
```

for each table.

Estimated total rows count is `2e9`.

Suppose ARCHIVELOG mode is on, so during those updates a lot of extra space is going to be consumed.

The process of updates is planned to be running in production DB simultaneously with business transactions, which should not be lost.

The simplest thing to start with is temporarily installing plenty of hardware for ARCHIVELOG files.

Is there an elegant way to achieve the same goal programmatically or via tuning "secret options"?

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Do not perform an `UPDATE` at all. Just add it as new column with the default value of `HELLO`.

It took 0.12 seconds and generated an insignificant amount of redo in my sandbox:

```
SQL> select force_logging from v$database;

FORCE_LOGGING
---------------------------------------
YES

SQL> set timing on
SQL> select count(*) from t1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
1000000000

Elapsed: 00:00:14.34

SQL> select sn.name, ss.value from v$statname sn 
     join v$sesstat ss on (sn.statistic# = ss.statistic#)
     where ss.sid = sys_context('userenv', 'sid') and sn.name = 'redo size';

NAME            VALUE
---------- ----------
redo size        5964

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00

SQL> alter table t1 add my_meta varchar2(20 char) default 'HELLO' not null;

Table altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.12
SQL> select sn.name, ss.value from v$statname sn 
     join v$sesstat ss on (sn.statistic# = ss.statistic#)
     where ss.sid = sys_context('userenv', 'sid') and sn.name = 'redo size';

NAME            VALUE
---------- ----------
redo size       20408

SQL> select count(*) from t1 where my_meta = 'HELLO';

  COUNT(*)
----------
1000000000

Elapsed: 00:01:00.96
```

Comment: That's impressive. The only problem is that `NOT NULL` is a significant part. Without it altering table takes lot of time and redo space. The same we have when afterwards trying to modify the column to be nullable.

Comment: The trick Balazs had shown is a feature of 11g.  With this syntax, the database is only modifying the metadata for the table.

Comment: @MichaelKutz, yes, actually this solution is valid while we use it separately in one DB. For instance, dump of this table would still have `NULL`s in `MY_META` column and it may cause problems.

Comment: @diziaq And the import of the dump will also set the metadata and the result will be the same.

Comment: On Oracle 11 (any release) a dump of the table will contain `NULL` instead of values for `my_meta` - it's tested. I suppose in Oracle 12 there's a similar situation, and it's obvious that we cannot get that blazing fast default values for millions of rows for free. Anyway, I find your answer useful, so I've upvoted.